# What do the correct arguments for Date dayMonthYearDo: look like in Smalltalk (Pharo / Squeak)

Tags: date, smalltalk, pharo, squeak

```
Date dayMonthYearDo: aBlock 
"Supply integers for day, month and year to aBlock and return the result"

^ start dayMonthYearDo: aBlock
```

What should a typical valid block look like for this message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case the comment "Supply integers, etc." means that the argument `aBlock` will receive three integers as "actual" arguments: *day number*, *month index* and *year*. This means that you will have to create a block with three "formal" arguments, say, `day`, `monthIndex` and `year` as in:

```
aDate dayMonthYearDo: [:day :monthIndex :year | <your code here>]
```

The code you write inside `<your code here>` can refer to the "formal" parameters `day`, `monthIndex` and `year`, much as if it was a method with these three arguments.

This is how blocks generally work in Smalltalk.

**Example**

```
aDate
    dayMonthYearDo: [:day :monthIndex :year |
        monthIndex + day = 2
            ifTrue: [Transcript show: 'Happy ' , year asString, '!']]
```

**UPDATE**

The example above checks for January 1st by "ingeniously" comparing `monthIndex + day` with `2`. In fact, since both variables are >= 1 the only way to get `2` is when `day` and `monthIndex` are both `1`, i.e., when the receiver `aDate` is January 1. A more "serious" approach would look like

```
(monthIndex = 1 and: [day = 1]) ifTrue: [ <etc> ]
```

Comment: But _please_ don't use `monthIndex + day = 2` to check if it's Jan 1st :)

Comment: @mgarciaisaia that was my joke!

Comment: Okay, I started off with one question - now that I have (two) correct answers, I now have 3 questions. It's also apparent to me I I had misunderstood the purpose of the pre-defined Date>>dayMonthYearDo: method.

So my new questions:

1) Is Date>>dayMonthYearDo: simply a placeholder for some future to-be-defined method, that is actually defined in the block?  And the answer here is "Yes", I now realise.

2) Here, how does the object "aDate" supply the day monthIndex and year values that are used in the block?  Automagically?  Is the receiver being an instance of Class Date a red herring?

Comment: @EuanM Please create a new question (or two) instead of using the comments. That will facilitate more contributions.

Comment: @Leandro Already done, for question 3.

But question 2) above is a question on the workings of the code you posted as your answer.  Surely the correct thing to do is to ask in this thread?

Comment: Ok, as I currently understand it.

What the dayMonthYearDo: method does is provide the three integers represented day, month and year from the instance of Date.  It then provides them as parameters to the block that follows (i.e the block that is provided as the keyword message argument).  It then evaluates the block, and returns the result of the evaluation of the block.

Comment: That's correct. There is nothing "magic" about Smalltalk, in the sense that everything can be understood, learned and even changed.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
Date today dayMonthYearDo: [:d :m :y| Transcript cr; 
        show: 'today is the ';
        show: d;
        show: 'th'
        ]

today is the 28th
```

But of course you may do different things that just showing things on transcript

Comment: Thank you for the correct answer. 

What I had been hoping to accomplish was finding the pre-existing method on Date or DateAndTime that would allow me to alter the day, monthIndex and year to set values e.g. 07 11 1984

I shall ask a new question.